# PIL has no ImageTk attribute

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

why would this work:

```
...
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
.... 
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("One.jpg"))
...
```

but this

```
...
import PIL as p
.... 
img = p.ImageTk.PhotoImage(p.Image.open("One.jpg"))
...
```

tells me `module 'PIL' has no attribute 'ImageTk'`?

I thought that I could import PIL as p then use anything in PIL in my code as long as it's preceded by p.

I'd like to avoid using `from PIL import Image, ImageTk` because I like to have the context of which modules bits of code come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIL's `__init__.py` is an empty stub as is common. It will not import all modules.

So when you try: `from PIL import ImageTk` it search in the PIL package folder and finds the file ImageTk.py and imports that.

But when you try: `PIL.ImageTk` you are actually doing an attribute lookup on the PIL module.

To avoid confusion you could do:

`from PIL import Image as Pil_image, ImageTk as Pil_imageTk`

So that you give the class a name thats tells you where it comming from.

Comment: thanks. So it seems that `import [module] as ...` probably isn't the best way to import stuff. It's a shame that it won't work for a lot of modules because I think it that being able to preface commands with something denoting the module that they come from would make my code a lot more intuitive. The work around is more verbose at the importing stage, but still works.